# fetch the recently added 10 recods from mogodb in express,js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i am trying to create a api that can fetch recently added  10 records every time the api is called  from the data base is there a method to do that

i have this code which can access all the records how i limit only the first 10

```
app.get("/questapi", function (req, res) {
    mydb
      .collection("questions")
      .find({})
      .toArray(function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.send(data);
      });
  });
```

every time i call the api it should get  recently added 10
i am fetching from mogodb

Comment: What is the criteria to determine the document is in the recent or in the past?

Comment: recent 10 records

Comment: You can possibly know that by some condition - like insert timestamp, or date or the ObjectId value of _id field.

Comment: no is it posible to fetch randomly 10 reords?

Comment: Random 10 records and recent 10 records are _not_ the same.

Comment: i do not have any entry that can pick first 10 records

Comment: What is your document structure? You an post a sample document in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
app.get("/questapi", function (req, res) {
    mydb
      .collection("questions")
      .find()
      .limit(10);  //here you can limit how many elements you want to retrieve
      .toArray(function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.send(data);
      });
  });
```

Comment: i am getting Declaration or statement expected  error

Comment: .toArray(f  starting of this line

Comment: what am doing worng here

Comment: did you try changing .find({}) to .find() and viceversa?

Comment: yes tryed but still error not going

Comment: can you show the full error message

Comment: the error was  ; after .limit(10)

Comment: but this is fetching only the oldest added 10 records  what i want is the recently added 10 records

Comment: try adding `.sort({_id:-1})` or `.sort({_id:1})` whichever works. Add it before `.limit(10)`